# Pausing particular thread in iOS?

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsthread

in my iPhone app, I have used 2 threads. Both functions differently in different class. On particular condition I want to pause particular thread so I have used
`[NSThread sleepForTimeInterval:]`
So my question is am I doing right or this sleep causes sleep in whole application? If yes what is other alternative?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to pause your thread for a given amount of time, then `[NSThread sleepForTimeInterval:]` is just fine. However if you want to wait for a given event to occur (e.g. wait for another thread to catch up) you should take a look at the `NSCondition` class.

Answer (score 1):

Yeah this is absolutely right. This will pause the current thread on which you are calling `[NSThread sleepForTimeInterval:]`